# Angular 7 - $(...).popover is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, angular7, openlayers

es la primera vez que hago una pregunta por acá, por lo general siempre encuentro la solución pero en este caso no sé que es.

Estoy practicando y se me ocurrió hacer una web con un mapa y diferentes marcadores, quería que al posicionarte o al hacerle click te aparezca X info.

Venía siguiendo los ejemplos de OpenLayers pero llegué a este punto y no puedo avanzar, me aparece el error "$(...).popover is not a function".

Les dejo el link al github para que puedan ver todo.

Github: https://github.com/LeandroLescano/LocalMap/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toda la logica que depende de que la View se haya inicializado debe ir en `ngAfterViewInit()` en lugar de `onInit()`. El codigo que pongas en OnInit no tiene la garantia de que todos tus componentes esten cargados en la pantalla.

El motivo por el que recibes el error "is not a function" es porque `$(element)` no devuelve ningun elemento.

Aparte de ello, jQuery no se lleva bien con Angular ya que ambas librerias hacen manipulacion del DOM. Te recomendaria que usases, si puedes, funciones puras de Angular (como ViewChild) o la propia libreria Renderer2 que viene con Angular.